# Adding multiple listbox results in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, count, listbox

I am creating a form that will show the total cost of a rental based on:

**total time used**
the **amenities selected**

Right now I have the **total time used** calculated and reported in *[Text31]*
We charge $250 for the first 3 hours and then $100 for each additional hour.

I show this as:
    =([Text31]-3)*100+250

We also charge $50 for each amenity selected. There are three: Kitchen, A/V Equipment and a Stage. They are shown in a listbox that allows multiple selections. I would like to add $50 to the total when a check box is selected.

Is there a way to count the items selected so I could then multiply the count by 50? Then I could add that to the existing total.

Comment: Screenshots may help us provide better answers for you.  Is this a drop-down box for the customer to select, or just a calculated field?

Comment: This is a listbox with three options for the user to select. Just started using this site so I will post a screenshot as soon as I figure out how. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response. I have the problem figured out now.
I used the formula below to add $50 when an item in the listbox was selected.

=([Text31]-3)*100+250+([Amenities].[ItemsSelected].[Count]*50)